# Change the startup directory to something other than HOME

Tags: fish

By default, when I open the fish shell, my working directory is the home directory. Is there a way to change the default working directory on startup, without having to edit the HOME variable?

Comment: perhaps add `cd /wanted/startup/directory` to the end of your `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fish does not change your CWD to $HOME when it starts. When you launch a shell from a terminal, the terminal will normally have set CWD to your home directory. Your terminal may provide a way to set a different CWD when launching the shell. If it doesn't, then add something like this to your *~/.config/fish/config.fish*:

```
if status is-login
    cd /my/preferred/starting/directory
end
```

Comment: So the CWD on startup is a concern for the terminal, not the shell? In that case it's good that Fish provides some way of setting the CWD even though it isn't Fish' concern. Thanks for the pragmatic solution, Glenn and Kurtis :)

Comment: @jallersma, Yes, more or less. The CWD that fish (or any other shell) inherits is whatever the parent program decides it should be. Your question is also applicable to other shells such as bash, zsh, ksh, elvish, etc.